# Primefaces 1.1 and jsf1.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-1.2

Can anybody share me an example using primefaces 1.1 and jsf 1.2 , and the required jar files?

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces 1.1 and 1.2 both's jar file and examples(In userguide) are available on following link...

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/downloads/list